# Show that any subset of $\{1, 2, 3, ..., 200\}$ having more than $100$ members must contain at least one pair of integers which add to $201$.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

Show that any subset of $\{1, 2, 3, ..., 200\}$ having more than $100$ members must contain at least one pair of integers which add to $201$.

I think it is doable using the Pigeonhole Principle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the subset {$1,2,3,...,100$}. No two integers from this set sum to $201$. However, the very next integer you include in this set gives you the smallest subset with more than $100$ integers in it where two of the integers sum to $201$. Any other subset of the desired size will always have two integers whose sum is $201$. Thus any subset of {$1,2,3,...,200$} that contains more than $100$ integers must contain at least one pair of integers whose sum is $201$.

Comment: How do you justify "Any other subset of the desired size will always have two integers whose sum is 201"? That's exactly what must be proved.

Answer (score 6):

Hint:  think about the pairs that add to $201$.  How many such pairs are there?

Comment: there are 100 pairs ... (1,200)... (50, 151)... (100, 101).

Comment: Correct.  And you have to pick $101$ numbers....

Comment: Is it enough to say that the sum adds to 201, and there are 100 pairs. Then take the floor of 201/100, and it shows that there is at least one pair that adds to 201.

Comment: You are not using the pigeonhole principle.  To avoid a sum of 201, how many numbers of your 101 can come from any given pair?

Comment: I dont understand your question.

Comment: In my batch of $101$ numbers, if I don't want to have a pair summing to $201$, I can't have both $1$ and $200$, nor both $2$ and $199$, nor ...  So I can pick $100$ numbers by taking one from each pair.  Now when I try to pick one more...

Comment: If I try to pick one more so that it doesn't add to 201, that number could be any other but the one that adds to 201

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11269/discussion-between-ross-millikan-and-orchid-fibio)